# typescript mark function as implementing an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, types

I want to indicate that a function is expected to implement a certain interface.

For example:

```
import { BrowserEvents, eventHandler, Event } from './browser-events'; 

export function setup(){
 const browserEvents = new BrowserEvents();
 browserEvents.onClicks(handleClicks);

 function handleClicks(ev: Event) {
   ev.preventDefault();
 }
}
```

I would like to tell typescript that `handleClicks` should match type `eventHandler`. Obviously, if the signature of `handleClicks` doesn't match `onClicks`, ts will throw an error. But I would like to show the error 'at the source' like this syntax:

```
// (not valid syntax!)
function handleClicks(ev: Event) implements eventHandler {
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

I could also use the function as a variable, like so, but it would force me to move the function before its usage:

```
const handleClicks: eventHandler = (ev: Event) => {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

browserEvents.onClicks(handleClicks);
```

so, is there a syntax to force a regular function to comply to a signature?

Answer (score -1):

think you might be able to do something like this:

(but not sure what you're trying to return so I have typed it as `void`)

```
interface FunctionInterface {
  (e: eventHandler): void;
}

function f1(e): FunctionInterface {
  e.preventDefault();
}

const f2: FunctionInterface = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
};
```

Comment: nice, but `function foo(): SomeType { }` sets `SomeType` to be the return value of `foo`.

Comment: did you reference the `SomeType` as an interface with the function syntax like above? Ive just tested it out in a repl

Comment: Yes. [See Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBBBuEDtgAkCGCAmAbCAnKAvFAM7C4CWCA5gFA2XB4BmqAxtAGICuCrw5AewQBJJMzbQA3jShQAFBABcMeEjSYcuAJTLYA8hgDcNAL50mPPoIRQmARgU6o3XvyGjGuFuyjTZEADowXDhEYAARCBYuLGA5LWNZViFSKFRCKABmRKgQ4C5cG1RjMxpkhFSmACZlFyt3MS8JDIVldBAtQgA+XxkYIJDVCKjUGLitU0MgA). Getting error - `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'FunctionInterface'.(2322)`